# installing scrapy mac os 10.7.5

Tags: macos, python-2.7, scrapy

I'm trying to install scrapy, but when I enter scrapy startproject tutorial at the command line it gives me an error. I installed with

`sudo easy_install scrapy`

I have searched Google and stackoverflow and a lot of answers suggest that scrapy hasn't been properly added to my PATH. Well, I can find scrapy at

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy
```

But even after adding the following line to my ~/.bash_profile, scrapy still doesn't work:

```
 export PATH=/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages:$PATH
```

I'm not that confident that I've done this right. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide your error message in detail? If we have your error message screenshot, we'll be able to re-trigger the error then figure out what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add /usr/local/bin into your PATH

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

#### Update

While you install scrapy via easy_install, your should see something like

```
Adding Scrapy 0.18.4 to easy-install.pth file
installing scrapy script to /usr/local/bin
```

Try to uninstall it first, then reinstall it and check where the script is installed

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't work. :( I don't know how to put the commands on separate lines in the comments, but I did the following.
~ $ export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH                               
~ $ scrapy startproject tutorial                                     
-bash: scrapy: command not found

Answer (score -1):

“pip3 install scrapy” has solved my problem. Can you try this?